# APK file from react app (not react-native)

Tags: reactjs, apk, mobile-application, apollo

It is any possibility to generate apk file from react app (not react-native), by including only manifest.json file to the project? App is build on react + apollo.

Comment: It should be theoretically possible but I would advice against it

Comment: @KostasPelelis why? It's bad practice to compile web app to standalone apk file?